# use a regex to split a pipe(|) separated string but ignore pipes in brackets

Tags: php, regex

Suppose I have a string like this in php(laravel):

```
make|aaa|select.aaa|ttt|actived_by(creator.url|test|ali)
```

Now I want to convert it to an array like this:

```
make
aaa
select.aaa
tttt
actived_by(creator.url|test|ali)
```

As you can see only pipe signs that are not included in brackets used to separation.

For that I wrote a function like this :

```
function parseQuery($query) {
    preg_match_all("/[^\|]+/", $query, $match);
    return $match;
}
```

But it has below output:

```
make
aaa
select.aaa
ttt
actived_by(creator.url
test
ali)
```

What is proper regex to use for desired result ?

Comment: Intreesting problem. You can extract the bracketed stuff with `#\w+\([^\)]+\)#`, leaving you with the other ones https://regex101.com/r/e3wxtt/1

Comment: Just use `preg_split('~\|(?![^()]*\))~', $s)`

Comment: I hope I am not too late. According to python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) you should add backslash to avoid issues, Let me know if this solves your issue.

Comment: Can there be cases like `make|aaa|(select.aaa|(ttt|actived_by(creator.url|test|ali)))` (to be split into 3 elements)?

Comment: maybe its be like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of splitting, it may also make sense to use `preg_match_all` using this regex:

`/[^|(]+(\([^)]+\))?/`

This will capture a string with no parenthesis or pipes `[^(]+`, optionally followed by a section encapsulated by parenthesis `(\([^)]+\))?`

The regex is demoed here in javascript

```js
var input = "make|aaa|select.aaa|ttt|actived_by(creator.url|test|ali)"

console.log(input.match(/[^|(]+(\([^)]+\))?/g))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following regex instead:

```
(?=[^|])(?:[^|]*\([^)]+\))*[^|]*
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/CONoJ2/2

Comment: seems that it right but a problem that is an empty string generated alternate

Comment: I didn't. But I now think you mean that you want to avoid matching an empty string between two `|`s right?

Comment: In that case I've updated my answer to avoid matching an empty string between two `|`s.